# Why Golang ast.Field can have multiple names?

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

Just playing around with golang go/ast package.

I don’t quite understand why [ast.Field](https://pkg.go.dev/go/ast#Field) can have multiple names?

```golang
type Field struct {
    Doc     *CommentGroup // associated documentation; or nil
    Names   []*Ident      // field/method/(type) parameter names; or nil
    Type    Expr          // field/method/parameter type; or nil
    Tag     *BasicLit     // field tag; or nil
    Comment *CommentGroup // line comments; or nil
}
```

---

**Upd.**
Thanks to the @kurtis-rader

I want to create cli tool that will generate struct conversion functions from one struct type to another. Here [in this](https://github.com/tymbaca/structconv/blob/main/generate/generate.go#L141-L145) place I need to choose which name of `Field` to pass into struct literal as a key and value

Comment: This type of question is better suited for the golang-nuts@googlegroups.com mailing list. Also, more context would help. Specifically, what code did you write where the values of a `type Field` confused you? Or what code are you trying to write that involves the use of a `type Field`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ast.Field represents a field declaration (and other things with a similar syntax).  A field declaration can have more than one identifier.

Here is the syntax from
the [specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Struct_types):

```
StructType    = "struct" "{" {     FieldDecl ";" } "}" .
FieldDecl     = (IdentifierList Type |     EmbeddedField) [ Tag ] .
EmbeddedField = [ "*" ] TypeName [ TypeArgs ] .
Tag          = string_lit .
```

Example:

```
struct {
    A, B int 
}
```

Comment: So go parser interprets "A, B int" as 1 ast.Field object..?